# How do i remove a item in a object if i did not know the key name in MongoDB?

Tags: python, database, mongodb

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF4be.png)

Please refer the image, Here i want to delete bearing_accelerometer_sensor field but i dont know this key name but i know the value here (i.e ObjectId("618e3fc8fccb88b50f2d9317")), I'm aware we can use this query `db.getCollection('algorithm_association_collection').update({},{"$unset":{"sensor.bearing_accelerometer_sensor":""}})` to delete the field but in my case i dont know the key name "bearing_accelerometer_sensor". Pls help thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      sensor: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$sensor" },
          cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.v", ObjectId("618e3fc8fccb88b50f2d9317") ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { sensor: { $arrayToObject: "$sensor" } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Ywb2PibWYt)

If you like to update existing collection, you can use the pipeline in an `update` statement:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      sensor: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$sensor" },
          cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.v", ObjectId("618e3fc8fccb88b50f2d9317") ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { sensor: { $arrayToObject: "$sensor" } } }
])
```